# How to fix "Error in flextable: invalid col_keys, flextable support only syntactic names" in downloadHanler

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have Shiny Server as follows:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){

  t1 <- reactive({
    tab1 <- data.table("Fields"=c("Contact Person",
                                        "Cost Center:",
                                        "Department:",
                                        "Date:"

                       "Detailed information" = c(input$`Contact Person`,
                                                  input$`Cost`,
                                                  input$`Department`,
                                                  format(input$`Date`[1])


    tab1

  })
        output$tbl1 <- renderTable({
    if (is.null(t1()))
      return(NULL)
    t1()
  })
```

output$download1 = downloadHandler(

```
filename = function(){
  paste("InternalRequest_",Sys.Date(),".docx", sep ="")

},
content = function(file){

  ft <- flextable(t1())
  ft <- theme_vanilla(ft)

  doc = read_docx(path="B:\\Desktop\\Internal Request.docx")
  doc<-doc%>%cursor_bookmark("DATA")
  doc<-body_add_flextable(doc, ft, pos = "on")

  print(doc, file = file)
})
 })
```

The download doesnt work, and I received the message "Warning: Error in flextable: invalid col_keys, flextable support only syntactic names". Could anyone help me to solve the Problems? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I giving my suggestion, based on my understand. Yes before passing your reactive dataset into flextable we should have keep proper colnames. For example in your case the colnames of reactive dataset contains space **(Detailed information)**. For making proper colnames, I am using function **clean_names()** from **janitor** package. Use following code

```
 library(janitor)
  t1() %>% 
   clean_names() %>%
   flextable() %>% 
   theme_vanilla() %>%
   set_header_labels(fields = "Fields",detailed_information = "Detailed information") -> ft
```

instead of

```
ft <- flextable(t1())
ft <- theme_vanilla(ft)
```

inside your **downloadHandler**

Thanks.

Comment: that's a correct answer. However the new version now support non syntatic names - it will be on cran in 2/3 days. You can also get it from Github

Comment: that's great. I am looking forward with new version. Thanks!